# GridEngine qstat no output?

Tags: scala, sungridengine

I'm trying to write a simple program to fire off some qstat commands, and collate some relevant information.

The first step of this is to run some a simple

```
qstat -u '*'
```

which I can then parse to work out the currently running jobs (doesn't seem to be an easy way to just list ths job ids)

This command works completely fine when run from a terminal. My problem is that this command doesn't seem to work when run through Scala process:

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._

scala> val qstatOutput = "qstat -u '*'" !!
qstatOutput: String = ""
```

This is particularly confusing, since if I add a `-f`, the output works fine:

```
scala> val qstatOutput = "qstat -f -u '*'" !!
qstatOutput: String = "queuename                      qtype resv/used/tot. load_avg arch          states..."
```

Can anyone suggest why this might not be working?

Answer (score 2):

Are there jobs running? By default `qstat -u '*'` will report nothing if no jobs are running, whereas `qstat -f -u '*'` will report rows with statistics on each queue/host combination.

Edit: added markup.